# IE 8 Array iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer, debugging

Hi I'm debugging my page for IE8 compat mode, and this script just doesn't like to work and crushes.

Basically it had to iterate through a 3D array, and add a local path to a variable. Well I could do it otherwise, but I'm just curious why the **** it never works...

Any suggestions are welcome :) Here's the code:

```
for(i=0;i<menu_items_p.length;i++)
for(j=0;j<menu_items_p[i].length;j++)
menu_items_p[i][j][1]='http://127.0.0.1/'+menu_items_p[i][j][1];
```

and the array looks something like this:

```
var menu_items_p =
[
    [   //Products
        ['Health Care', 'products/health.php'],
        ['Aroma Therapy','products/scents.php'],
    ],
            [      // Empty
             ],
    [   //Test
        ['What ever', 'spirulina/about.php'],
    ]
]
```

The problem though is that it sometimes have empty values, and array.length triggers some error...

Comment: If the array can have empty values, then you'll have to check for that case. Just write a few extra lines of code and you're done.

Comment: it's not that easy. What worked perfectly IE9, now just doesn't work........... (typeof menu_items_p[i].length!="undefined") triggers errors too, so its better you tell us what exactly code shall we put, and check it with IE8 compat mode first.. Thanks

Comment: What error do you get? What does `typeof menu_item_p[i]` return? (and you should really use curly brackets there and declare the variables properly)

Comment: test if `menu_items_p[i] !== undefined`, this isn't really a problem of the browser, it's a problem that you're not testing your data correctly/sufficiently. If the data can be this varying you'll have to check for it.

Comment: Your code is leaking globals. Use `var i` and `var j`!

Comment: Thanks for two great advices, Yoshi and Thiefmaster... This had solved it =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS suggested by Yoshi and ThiefMaster, I made it following, and this is what solved it:

```
for(var i=0;i<menu_items_p.length;i++)
if (menu_items_p[i] !== undefined)
for(var j=0;j<menu_items_p[i].length;j++)
if (menu_items_p[i][j] !== undefined)
menu_items_p[i][j][1]='http://127.0.0.1/'+menu_items_p[i][j][1];
```

1. Global vars replaced.
2. Check for undefined.

It's a pity they didn't answer in a formal way, so I would have to answer my self :)
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

When used your original array declaration:

```
var menu_items_p =
[
    [   //Products
        ['Health Care', 'products/health.php'],
        ['Aroma Therapy','products/scents.php'],
    ],
            [      // Empty
             ],
    [   //Test
        ['What ever', 'spirulina/about.php'],
    ]
]
```

error occurs in IE8 but not in IE9. Just remove two commas:

```
var menu_items_p =
[
    [   //Products
        ['Health Care', 'products/health.php'],
        ['Aroma Therapy','products/scents.php'] // here comma removed
    ],
            [      // Empty
             ],
    [   //Test
        ['What ever', 'spirulina/about.php'] // here comma removed
    ]
]
```

and all must work fine.

Comment: unfortunetely this wasn't the problem, the commas were ok in the original code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code could handle empty values this way:

```
for(var i = 0; i < menu_items_p.length; i++) {
    // we skip the value if it is empty or an empty array 
    if(!menu_items_p[i] || !menu_items_p[i].length) continue; 
    for(var j = 0; j < menu_items_p[i].length; j++) {
       // again, we skip the value if it is empty or an empty array
       if(!menu_items_p[i][j] || !menu_items_p[i][j].length) continue;
       menu_items_p[i][j][1] = 'http://127.0.0.1/' + menu_items_p[i][j][1];
    }
}
```